# how to add resolution 1920x1080i with 60 fps and increase display scaling?

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, display, display-resolution

my display support 1920x1080i resolution with 60 fps i want to put that permanently

the output of xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1344 x 756, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 connected 1344x756+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1600mm x 900mm
   1360x768      60.02 +
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00*   59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1152x864      59.97  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x576i      50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to display application , second option will be of resolution , click that .Change into maximum resolution available , and it will be changed permanently.